# radio button group with dropdown button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, radio-button

Hi I want to create a group of radio buttons with bootstrap where the last button is a dropdown button here is the code I have so far, basically I want the last button to be a drop down

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label id='Radio 1' class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Radio 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Radio 4
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to try and do? You could put build your dropdown menu using a bootstrap single button dropdown, see below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id='Radio 1' class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Radio 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <input type="radio" class="" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Radio 4 <span class="caret"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap Single button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)

Comment: Yess, this is exactly what I am trying to do, except, there is one more thing, the way you have it now is that when anyone of the first 3 buttons is clicked and then the radio 4 is clicked, the button clicked before then remains clicked, 

what I want is that when 4 is clicked, the button clicked before then should become unclicked

Answer (score 1):

A one solution could be to remove the active class when the dropdown is toggled:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $('.btn').removeClass('active');
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/uLa818o3/

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that solved the remaining part of my problem